# How do I convert an integer value to decimal value in COBOL

Tags: cobol

How do I convert an integer value to decimal value in COBOL?

I need to display 1234567 as 12345.67

I cannot divide the variable by 100.

Answer (score 7):

COBOL provides several numeric representations. Some facilitate
arithmetic operations, others facilitate presentation. It takes
a while to sort them all out.

I think you may be looking for an implied decimal representation. The implied
decimal is indicated by the letter 'V' in a PICture string for example:

```
  WS-INT-NBR       PIC 9(7).
  WS-DEC-NBR       PIC 9(5)V99.
```

Both of the above declarations contain 7 digits and occupy 7 bytes of storage. 
You can assign the 
value 1234567 to WS-INT-NBR as follows:

```
  MOVE 1234567 TO WS-INT-NBR
```

but doing the same to WS-DEC-NBR would
cause an overflow (truncation) because it can only hold 5 digits before
an implied decimal point (the 'V'). However if you were to do the following:

```
 MOVE 12345.67 TO WS-DEC-NBR
```

the actual contents of WS-DEC-NBR would be `1234567` (notice the decimal point
is gone and it contains a value equivalent to WS-INT-NBR). That is what is meant by implied
decimal point. COBOL 'knows' that WS-DEC-NBR has a decimal point between the
5th and 6th digits but does not actually store it. Any operations applied
to WS-DEC-NBR will take the implied decimal point into consideration.

Armed with this knowledge you can then make use of another COBOL feature, the
REDEFINES declaration. REDEFINES tells the compiler to apply different
data type processing rules to the *same storage area*. In one case you want to
treat the memory area like an integer: PIC 9(7); and in other cases like an implied decimal 
value: PIC 9(5)V99).
Do this as follows:

```
 01.
     02 WS-INT-NBR   PIC 9(7).
     02 WS-DEC-NBR REDEFINES WS-INT-NBR PIC 9(5)V99.
```

Now WS-INT-NBR and WS-DEC-NBR occupy the same memory area (the same 7 bytes). However 
when you reference
WS-INT-NBR the integer representation is used. When you reference WS-DEC-NBR the decimal
representation is used.

That gets us over the 'not dividing by 100' part of your problem. The next bit is
displaying the decimal point when you need to. COBOL provides DISPLAY formats containing
explicit 'punctuation' of which the decimal point is one. For example:

```
 01  WS-DEC-DISPLAY    PIC 9(5).99.
```

WS-DEC-DISPLAY contains an explicit decimal point within its PICture clause (do not
confuse the period at the end of the line with the imbedded PICture clause decimal point). 
The content of WS-DEC-DISPLAY contains an explicit decimal point. So, to get the decimal
point to display you need to MOVE something with an implied decimal point to it, as in:

```
 MOVE WS-DEC-NBR TO WS-DEC-DISPLAY
```

if WS-DEC-NBR contained '1234567', WS-DEC-DISPLAY will contain '12345.67' after the MOVE.

The following program and displays put it all together for you:

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                            
   PROGRAM-ID. EXAMPLE.                                
   DATA DIVISION.                                      
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                            
   01.                                                 
       02 WS-INT-NBR   PIC 9(7).                         
       02 WS-DEC-NBR REDEFINES WS-INT-NBR PIC 9(5)V99. 

   01  WS-DEC-DISPLAY    PIC 9(5).99.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                 
       MOVE 1234567 TO WS-INT-NBR                      
       MOVE WS-DEC-NBR TO WS-DEC-DISPLAY               
       DISPLAY 'WS-INT-NBR    : ' WS-INT-NBR           
       DISPLAY 'WS-DEC-NBR    : ' WS-DEC-NBR           
       DISPLAY 'WS-DEC-DISPLAY: ' WS-DEC-DISPLAY       

       ADD +1 TO WS-INT-NBR                            
       MOVE WS-DEC-NBR TO WS-DEC-DISPLAY               
       DISPLAY 'INT-NBR PLUS 1: ' WS-DEC-DISPLAY       

       ADD +1 TO WS-DEC-NBR
       MOVE WS-DEC-NBR TO WS-DEC-DISPLAY        
       DISPLAY 'DEC-NBR PLUS 1: ' WS-DEC-DISPLAY

       GOBACK                                   
       .
```

Output:

```
WS-INT-NBR    : 1234567 
WS-DEC-NBR    : 1234567 
WS-DEC-DISPLAY: 12345.67
INT-NBR PLUS 1: 12345.68   <= notice which digit incremented
DEC-NBR PLUS 1: 12346.68   <= notice which digit incremented
```

Comment: Thats a worthy explanation NealB. `Hates off to your patience`

Answer (score 1):

Redefine your value using an implied decimal.  E.G.

```
10 ws-integer                      pic 9(7) value 1234567.
10 ws-decimal redefines ws-integer pic 9(5)v99.
```

When you refer to this as ws-decimal, you will get 12345.67.

So if you move something to ws-integer, you can access it with the decimals in the correct position using the other field.

Comment: i tried that, however after doing this i m getting vale as 34567.00

Comment: You must be doing a "Move ws-integer to ws-decimal" you need to redefine the data area.